# Can I download games-on-demand from foreign market places?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm in Germany and connect to Xbox Live using a German IP, but I've always used a fake address so I can see the UK marketplace.

(Disclaimer: This is because the German market place filters out any content that is rated 18+. I know this is not strictly legal, but I'm an adult and I can decide myself which content is appropriate for me)

The problem is, at some point in 2007 or so MS added an IP filter, so even with my UK account, I still cannot access all content (for instance, I cannot download Duke Nukem, since it's on the index in Germany so it's blacklisted for German IP addresses). The same is true for video on demand, I cannot watch anything (not even cartoons!) on the Zune market place.

But does that extend to games on demand, too? I would try it myself, but you must get past the payment screen in order to download, and even though I'm sure I wouldn't get charged if the download is inaccessible, I don't have enough MS points right now to make the purchase, so I cannot try.

Has anyone here ever tried accessing Games On Demand from other market places?

Answer (score 1):

How are you using a fake IP address? Microsoft may be using geolocation (detecting the real IP and finding the location) which filters out your content prior to location or anything to detec the location of your IP address.

Possibly, they use your Xbox serial numbers, or whatever to identify the Xbox and where it may have been purchased (if you purchased your Xbox in Germany, then it's probably certain why).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I'm using a fake residency address, not a fake IP address. That way Xbox will log me into the UK Xbox Live service, but some contents will still be inaccessible due to the geo blocker. However, I've recently toyed with YourFreedom (http://www.your-freedom.net) to access XBL through a UK proxy. However, the routing seems to break when I do that via my MacBook. :-/

Comment: Hmmm, I guess YourFreedom is buggy that breaks your routing. I still cannot think of a solution for you to access strict content, but there's probably no way you can access, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure of full games but I downloaded the Saw 2 demo (not available in Australia) by creating a U.S. hotmail account, then using that to make an Xbox Live account. Once you sign in, you have access to whatever country your hotmail account is linked to. The demo then works fine.